ISO creation path issue - ISO not found after build
I am using GitHub Actions to build a custom Alpine Linux ISO. The ISO is successfully created in the ~/iso directory, but I am encountering issues when trying to access or copy it afterward. Specifically, I receive an error indicating that the ISO file is not found or accessible.
Here is the relevant part of my GitHub Actions workflow file:
name: Build Custom Alpine ISO

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: true
    
      - name: Setup Alpine Linux environment
        uses: jirutka/setup-alpine@v1
        with:
          branch: edge
    
      - name: Install required packages and build ISO
        shell: alpine.sh --root {0}
        run: |
          apk add --no-cache alpine-sdk alpine-conf syslinux xorriso squashfs-tools grub grub-efi doas alpine-base busybox openrc bash agetty
          echo "permit nopass root" | tee -a /etc/doas.conf
          abuild-keygen -i -a -n -q
          apk update
          mkdir -p ~/tmp ~/iso
          export TMPDIR=~/tmp
          cp -rf custom/* aports/scripts/
          cp ./custom/pppwn.tar.gz aports/scripts/
          chmod +x aports/scripts/*
          
          echo "Running mkimage.sh script..."
          sh aports/scripts/mkimage.sh --tag edge --outdir ~/iso --arch x86_64 --repository https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main --profile pppwn

          echo "Listing files in ~/iso after ISO creation:"
          ls -l ~/iso/
      
      - name: Ensure target directory exists
        run: |
          mkdir -p /home/runner/iso/
        
      - name: Copy ISO to shared location
        run: |
          echo "Copying ISO files from ~/iso/ to /home/runner/iso/"
          cp ~/iso/*.iso /home/runner/iso/
        
      - name: Check if ISO was copied and exists
        run: |
          echo "Listing files in /home/runner/iso:"
          ls -l /home/runner/iso/
          if [ -z "$(ls -A /home/runner/iso/*.iso 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
            echo "ISO not found in shared location. Exiting."
            exit 1
          fi

      - name: Upload ISO artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: pppwn-live-iso
          path: /home/runner/iso/*.iso

The ISO file alpine-pppwn-edge-x86_64.iso is correctly created in the ~/iso directory as indicated by the ls command output inside the Alpine container. Outside the container the ISO is not found.
I've Tried:

Ensuring the target directory /home/runner/iso/ exists before copying files.
Verifying that the ISO file is indeed present in ~/iso/ after the build step.
Adjusting paths in the workflow to be consistent and correct.


It's not found outside the container because it's inside the container. If you need to get files out of a container to the host (the runner) you need e.g. docker cp.

@jonrsharpe I use https://github.com/jirutka/setup-alpine and the README says "Please note that /home/runner/work (where’s your workspace located) is always mounted"

OK, but that's not the directory it's in - you're using /home/runner/iso/. And cp ~/iso/*.iso /home/runner/iso/ makes very little sense because, inside or outside the container, that's the same directory for the user runner.

@jonrsharpe yes you are correct, after saving it under /home/runner/work the ISO was successfully uploaded

Is it possible that when you are creating the file, home is /root because you are running as —root. When you are copying, you are running as user runner with a different hone.
